Weird usage of indices in the proof that closed sets are stable under intersections
it's the proof of "any intersection of closed sets is a closed set"
the book proposes the following:
let $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ a set of subindices, $\{C_d\}_{d\in K}$ a set of closed sets and $C= \bigcap_{d\in K}C_d.$
if $x\notin C$ then there exist $d\in K$ s.t. $x\notin C_d$ and $x\in\mathcal{C}C_d$. because $\mathcal{C}C_d$ is an open set, then there's a open neighborhood $U_x\subset\mathcal{C}C_d$. moreover, $U_x\cap C_d=\varnothing\Rightarrow U_x\cap C = \varnothing\Rightarrow U_x\subset\mathcal{C}C_d.$
Therfore, $\mathcal{C}C$ is an open set. and therefore C is a closed set.
I can't understand how or why $K\subset\mathbb{R}$, why it would be a set of subindices real numbers, like what does that mean there exists the 3.5th element in a set? how would that work in the operator $\bigcap$? the rest of the proof assuming all that I don't know, is true, I understand what it means but that:
"let $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ a set of subindices, $\{C_d\}_{d\in K}$ a set of closed sets and $C= \bigcap_{d\in K}C_d.$"

Don't use $k$ and $K$ interchangeably

oop mistype, I'll fix it, sorry!

Also, $\mathcal C$ is not a standard notation . Presumably it means complement?

It is weird to assume that sets must be indexed by real numbers, but there's nothing wrong with it.  For instance, $\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{R}} {k} = \mathbb{R}$.

If there isn't some context missing, I'd say you're right that it makes no sense.

Presumably, they want to limit the cardinality of the indices to #\leq|\mathbb R|.$ But it is strange.

@Randall I want to know why though, like I'm new to topology and this is way too weird because I've never seen this before

@Randall What is wrong with it is that the definition of topology doesn't put a size limitation on the condition that unions of open sets are open.

Except it is true for any cardinality. So  it is weird to even restrict the cardinalities.

@whateverowo  Like people said, without context it is hard to say.  The theorem ought to be stated with NO assumptions on the potential cardinality of $K$.

@ThomasAndrews yes $\mathcal{C}$ is complementary

Put it in the question.

Please add the title and author of the book. Then we know which book can be avoided.

@MartinBrandenburg it's the actuall book of my university, isbn 9788419947581

This one?.https://www.librosuned.com/LU32105/An%C3%A1lisis-matem%C3%A1tico--C%C3%A1lculo-diferencial-en-una-variable(P).aspx

@Randall well that's what I have, before that there's a definition of a closed set being the complementary of an open set, I'm so confused rn (╥﹏╥)

@MartinBrandenburg yes

@ThomasAndrews my question would be how $\bigcap_{d\in K}$ would work, like what does it mean to iterate over real numbers, is it even iterating, this is the first time I see this symbol and all I see in other places is with natural numbers, and also how that ${C_d}$ would work.

Let $S$ be a set, $K$ another set, and $(C_d)_{d\in K}$ a family of subsets of $S$. Then $\bigcap_{d\in K}C_d$ is defined as the set of all $x\in S$ with $x\in C_d$ for all $d\in K$. $K$ can be a completely arbitrary set. You don't need to assume that it is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, but it's not wrong if you do.
The problem in your concrete statement is that the author claims to prove that any intersection of closed sets is closed. If you then introduce $K$ by $K\subset\mathbb{R}$, you're not proving the claim for any intersection, but only for intersections that can be written as the intersection of a family indexed by a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
This would be kind of ok (but confusing) if all possible intersections could be written in that way. But that is not the case, since there are strictly more subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ than elements of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. we also have to consider intersections where the index set is bigger than $\mathbb{R}$ and can therefore not be regarded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Ohhh okay, that makes way more sense to me.
